# Ejabberd configuration issue

Tags: ssl, dns, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

## What I want to achieve is:

- I want to run XMPP service on separate subdomain like `xmpp.domain.com`
- But at the same time, to use usernames like `john@domain.com`(neither than john@xmpp.domain.com)
- to auto detect xmpp service's url `xmpp.domain.com` on jabber clients while using username like `john@domain.com`
- to correctly use ssl

Of course it might be, the way I think is not correct. If you have suggestion about it please comment me.

## What I've done is:

Created Debian 8 server

Executed

```
apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -y install ejabberd
dpkg-reconfigure ejabberd
```

- A hostname - `xmpp.domain.com.`
- An administrative user - `admin` and two times password

Placed ssl pem key for `domain.com` in `/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.pem`

Added all DNS records like

[image]

Then `service ejabberd restart`

Now when I try to register a new user like

`ejabberdctl register admin domain.com 12345`

It gives me an error message like, it's not allowed to register such username. But it allows when I enter

`ejabberdctl register admin xmpp.domain.com 12345`

## The problem is...

So basically I can't use username `admin@domain.com` while using server `xmpp.domain.com`. What am I missing? any suggestions?

Also I'm a bit confused about SSL config and pem file. My SSL certificate currently supports www.domain.com and domain.com. Do I have to buy ssl cert for xmpp.domain.com also?

Answer (score 2):

In the `dpkg-reconfigure` step, you should have used `domain.com` instead of `xmpp.domain.com`. ejabberd only needs to know the domain it should use for JIDs, it doesn't need to know the domain it is actually running on.

Your SRV records and SSL certificate are correct: if you want to use `admin@domain.com`, you have to have a certificate for `domain.com`.